# Remove Exact Strings From a File

Tags: linux, bash, regular-expression

How do I remove exact strings using `sed`, `tr` or `awk`

```
{98406c4acbf0f57b3ccbc923a6d507f422d9bd8656398f53433e}HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

What I want to remove is `HTTP/1.0 200 OK`
I tried to do `sed` but there is a **Forward Slash** that prevent me form removing the exact string. Also, when I used `tr` it removes all letter matches not an exact string.

Comment: if the `/` is an issue, either escape it or use a diffrent "delimeter" in your sed command

Comment: use another separator or put the `/` inside a bracket group, try e.g. `echo a/b |sed -e 's,/,x,'` or `... | sed -e 's/[/]/x/'`

Comment: Thanks a lot it works for me like `sed 's/HTTP\/1.0\ 200\ OK//g'`